# Overlay/Join two collections with Linq

Tags: c#, linq, collections

I have the following scenario:

List 1 has 20 items of type TItem, List 2 has 5 items of the same type. List 1 already contains the items from List 2 but in a different state. I want to overwrite the 5 items in List 1 with the items from List 2.

I thought a join might work, but I want to overwrite the items in List 1, not join them together and have duplicates.

There is a unique key that can be used to find which items to overwrite in List 1 the key is of type int

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the built in Linq .Except() but it wants an IEqualityComparer so use [a fluid version](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/linq/Fluid_Linq_Except.aspx?display=PrintAll) of .Except() instead.

Assuming an object with an integer key as you indicated:

```
public class Item
{
    public int Key { get; set; }
    public int Value { get; set; }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return String.Format("{{{0}:{1}}}", Key, Value);
    }
}
```

The original list of objects can be merged with the changed one as follows:

```
IEnumerable<Item> original = new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 }.Select(x => new Item
    {
        Key = x,
        Value = x
    });
IEnumerable<Item> changed = new[] { 2, 3, 5 }.Select(x => new Item
    {
        Key = x,
        Value = x * x
    });

IEnumerable<Item> result = original.Except(changed, x => x.Key).Concat(changed);
result.ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
```

output:

```
{1:1}
{4:4}
{2:4}
{3:9}
{5:25}
```

Answer (score 1):

LINQ isn't used to perform actual modifications to the underlying data sources; it's strictly a query language. You could, of course, do an outer join on `List2` from `List1` and select `List2`'s entity if it's not null and `List1`'s entity if it is, but that is going to give you an `IEnumerable<>` of the results; it won't actually modify the collection. You could do a `ToList()` on the result and assign it to `List1`, but that would change the reference; I don't know if that would affect the rest of your application.

Taking your question literally, in that you want to REPLACE the items in `List1` with those from `List2` if they exist, then you'll have to do that manually in a `for` loop over `List1`, checking for the existence of a corresponding entry in `List2` and replacing the `List1` entry by index with that from `List2`.

Answer (score 1):

As Adam says, LINQ is about querying. However, you can create a *new* collection in the right way using `Enumerable.Union`. You'd need to create an appropriate `IEqualityComparer` though - it would be nice to have `UnionBy`. (Another one for [MoreLINQ](http://code.google.com/p/morelinq/) perhaps?)

Basically:

```
var list3 = list2.Union(list1, keyComparer);
```

Where `keyComparer` would be an implementation to compare the two keys. [MiscUtil](http://pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/miscutil) contains a `ProjectionEqualityComparer` which would make this slightly easier.

Alternatively, you could use `DistinctBy` from MoreLINQ after concatenation:

```
var list3 = list2.Concat(list1).DistinctBy(item => item.Key);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution with GroupJoin.

```
        List<string> source = new List<string>() { "1", "22", "333" };
        List<string> modifications = new List<string>() { "4", "555"};
          //alternate implementation
        //List<string> result = source.GroupJoin(
        //    modifications,
        //    s => s.Length,
        //    m => m.Length,
        //    (s, g) => g.Any() ? g.First() : s
        //).ToList();

        List<string> result =
        (
            from s in source
            join m in modifications
            on s.Length equals m.Length into g
            select g.Any() ? g.First() : s
        ).ToList();

        foreach (string s in result)
            Console.WriteLine(s);
```

Hmm, how about a re-usable extension method while I'm at it:

```
    public static IEnumerable<T> UnionBy<T, U>
    (
        this IEnumerable<T> source,
        IEnumerable<T> otherSource,
        Func<T, U> selector
    )
    {
        return source.GroupJoin(
            otherSource,
            selector,
            selector,
            (s, g) => g.Any() ? g.First() : s
                );
    }
```

Which is called by:

```
List<string> result = source
  .UnionBy(modifications, s => s.Length)
  .ToList();
```