# How to join 2 complex linqs with override

Tags: c#, linq

I am using C# in a MVC web app.

In one of my methods I am selecting XML data from 2 different sources and populating the same nested class structure for each select.

So:

```
var list1 = new PreferencesModel()
{
    SectionModel = xDoc1.Root.Elements("section").Select(x => new SectionModel()
    {
        Name = x.Attribute("name").Value,
        PreferenceModel = x.Elements("preference").Select(
        y => new PreferenceModel()
        {
            Name = y.Attribute("name").Value,
            Default = bool)y.Element("default").Attribute("value"),
            Type = y.Attribute("type").Value
        }).ToList(),
    }).ToList()
};

var list2 = new PreferencesModel()
{
    SectionModel = xDoc2.Root.Elements("section").Select(x => new SectionModel()
    {
        Name = x.Attribute("name").Value,
        PreferenceModel = x.Elements("preference").Select(
        y => new PreferenceModel()
        {
            Name = y.Attribute("name").Value,
            Default = bool)y.Element("default").Attribute("value"),
            Type = y.Attribute("type").Value
        }).ToList(),
    }).ToList()
};
```

These are my Model Classes:

```
public class PreferencesModel
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Message to display to user on UI
    /// </summary>
    public string MessageToUser { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// Stores Preferences
    /// </summary>
    public IList<SectionModel> SectionModel { get; set; }
}

public class SectionModel
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Name of Section (for Grouping Purposes)
    /// </summary>
    public string Name { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// List of Preferences for this section
    /// </summary>
    public IList<PreferenceModel> PreferenceModel { get; set; }
}

public class PreferenceModel
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Type of HTML Control ie radio button, textbox
    /// </summary>
    public string Type { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// Name of Preference
    /// </summary>
    public string Name { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// Global Default Value if not set by User
    /// </summary>
    public bool Default { get; set; }
}
```

Now I want just 1 returning list. The business rules are:

List1 Sections/Preferences are the Master list. They will always
have the same entries or more than List2. If the same Section and

Preference exist in both lists then the default 'value' in List2
will take precedence.

Now, i can do this easily enough 'manually' by using an enumerator.  But, having fallen in love with Linq I was wondering whether there was a purely Linq way of doing this?

As my Linq skills are rated at beginner this situation has blown my mind.

But first, can it actually be done?

Thanks

ADDITONAL

So, what I am after are unique entries with List2 default value taking precedence

Comment: if these both return lists of PreferenceModels why can't you just .AddRange them together?

Comment: @MarshallTigerus thanks for your comment. But how would this help?

Comment: you have two lists....addrange would combine them into one list

Comment: that isnot what I want :)

Comment: Perhaps my question eeds clarification

Comment: Sorry I see the mistake now.  In code, no matter what you are doing it will likely require iteration, whether as part of a linq query or not.  I'm thinking how I'd do this in linq.

Comment: This might give you the answer you need: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/975538/overlay-join-two-collections-with-linq

Comment: since your linq is a bit long and both are same why dont you use one method to reduce some code? just merge lists and perform `DistinctBy` using `MoreLinq`.

Comment: @MarshallTigerus No need to be sorry. I appreciate your  time.  also, I think a linq would take longer but obviously cannot measure that yet. But maybe an enumerator would be more manageable

Comment: @MarshallTigerus thanks for link!

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary thanks Ishall look into those methods now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since according to your business rules `list1` is superset of `list2`, the pure LINQ solution would be to use [Left Outer Join](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb311040.aspx) for correlating the matching elements. So you join the first level elements, then the corresponding second level elements and so on. And don't forget to carefully handle the `null` "right side" (non matching) elements.

```
var result =
    (from prefs1 in list1
     join prefs2 in list2
        on prefs1.MessageToUser equals prefs2.MessageToUser
     into prefs2Group
     from prefs2 in prefs2Group.DefaultIfEmpty()
     select new PreferencesModel
     {
         MessageToUser = prefs1.MessageToUser,
         SectionModel =
            (from section1 in prefs1.SectionModel
             join section2 in prefs2 != null ? prefs2.SectionModel : Enumerable.Empty<SectionModel>()
                on section1.Name equals section2.Name
             into section2Group
             from section2 in section2Group.DefaultIfEmpty()
             select new SectionModel
             {
                 Name = section1.Name,
                 PreferenceModel =
                    (from pref1 in section1.PreferenceModel
                     join pref2 in section2 != null ? section2.PreferenceModel : Enumerable.Empty<PreferenceModel>()
                        on new { pref1.Name, pref1.Type } equals new { pref2.Name, pref2.Type }
                     into pref2Group
                     from pref2 in pref2Group.DefaultIfEmpty()
                     select new PreferenceModel
                     {
                         Name = pref1.Name,
                         Type = pref1.Type,
                         Default = pref2 != null ? pref2.Default : pref1.Default
                     }).ToList()
             }).ToList()
     }).ToList();
```